# Shifting N objects with Manim at the same time in different directions

Tags: transformation, python-3.8, manim

I have a list of dots of variable random length and I want to be able to apply a transform (shift in this case) to these objects with independence but at the same time.

```
list = [Dot(), Dot() ...] # Variable length
```

I am using the Manim Library by https://github.com/3b1b/manim by 3blue1brown.
As a note, other related posts don't solve my problem as they only work with a fix number of objects (dots).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following code from this [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/manim/comments/kirvwf/how_do_i_carry_out_n_different_animations_at_the/), used as an example, solves the problem:

```
import numpy as np

class DotsMoving(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        dots = [Dot() for i in range(5)]
        directions = [np.random.randn(3) for dot in dots]
        self.add(*dots) # It isn't absolutely necessary
        animations = [ApplyMethod(dot.shift,direction) for dot,direction in zip(dots,directions)]
        self.play(*animations) # * -> unpacks the list animations
```

Special thanks to [u/Xorlium](https://www.reddit.com/user/Xorlium/).

Answer (score 6):

Don't use `list`, it's a reserved word, use `VGroup` to contain objects:

```py
list_dots = VGroup(*[Dot() for _ in range(5)]) # 5 dots vgroup
# this is the same as:
# list_dots = VGroup(Dot(),Dot(),Dot(),Dot(),Dot())
# See 'list comprehension python' in google
list_dots.arrange(RIGHT)
list_dots.set_color(RED)
list_dots.shift(UP)
```

Comment: I don't think you quite understood me. Forget about the reserved word ... I want to be able to apply different transforms by just indexing it and self.play(ing) it at the same time instead of looping through them.